# debugging cpp in VS2010 error value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

One debugging issue came up to me and i cannot understand the situation. the pic attached is the snapshot. `pos` is a vector of integers. i dont understand why i cannot have

`pos[k]-pos[j]`

presenting correctly in the debugging window. the application is running fine and outputs are correct, though. i wonder if it is due to some IDE configuration. any comments are welcome.

[image]

Comment: It look like an IDE parsing bug, try to add spaces around your `minus` character, does it help?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The screenshot shows that `pos` is defined as: `std::vector<int>` or am I wrong?

Comment: @kolenda  adding spaces doesnt help

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  it was declared and it's a vector of integers. see the pic

Comment: Did you succeed with standalone `pos[k]` and `pos[j]`? Just a try: put them in parentheses `(pos[k])-(pos[j])`.

Comment: @harper i was abt to say that neight pos[1]-pos[2] nor pos[1] worked. besides, i dont think pos(1) is correct.

Comment: The debugger expression evaluator is not a C++ compiler.  Yes, the error message is misleading.

Comment: @STNYU The issue is that `operator []` for a vector is a function.  What you're doing is basically no different than trying to call a member function via the debugger.  Attempting to do that was always an issue with the VS debugger.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  just a quick follow-up, r u saying this is a bug already existing in VS for a while?

Comment: @STNYU - It isn't a bug, just a shortcoming of the debugger.  AFAIK the debugger is not able to execute function calls.  Maybe this has changed with the latest version, but since VC++ 1.0, function call execution "on the fly" was never implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which version of the standard library you're using, look in the watch window for vector's members and use them instead of operator []. For example with VS2013 this works in the watch window:

```
pos._Myfirst[ j ] - pos._Myfirst[ k ]
```

as _Myfirst is  a pointer to the vector's storage